# Matlab: How to align the axes of subplots when one of them contains a colorbar?

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

Minimal example:

```
[x,y,z] = peaks(50);
figure;
subplot(5,1,1:4);
pcolor(x,y,z);
shading flat;
colorbar;
subplot(5,1,5);
plot(x(end/2,:), z(end/2,:));
```

[image: output]

In this example I'd like to have the lower subplot show the cross-section of peaks along y=0 and the plot ending at the same position as the pcolor subplot, so that the x ticks are on identical positions. In fact, I don't need the duplicate x axis then. So,

> How to rescale the lower subplot such that the right limit matches the right limit of the upper one's plot part? (preferably such that the colorbar can be switched on/off without destroying that alignment)

(FYI I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5023085/321973) I can use the [linkaxes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linkaxes.html) command then to have a correct zoom behaviour in a second step)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just set the width of the second subplot to the width of the first by changing the `Position` property.

```
[x,y,z] = peaks(50);
figure;
ah1 = subplot(5,1,1:4); %# capture handle of first axes
pcolor(x,y,z);
shading flat;
colorbar;
ah2 = subplot(5,1,5); %# capture handle of second axes
plot(x(end/2,:), z(end/2,:));

%# find current position [x,y,width,height]
pos2 = get(ah2,'Position');
pos1 = get(ah1,'Position');

%# set width of second axes equal to first
pos2(3) = pos1(3);
set(ah2,'Position',pos2)
```

You can then further manipulate your axes properties, for example you can turn of the x-labels on the first plot, and move the second one up so that they touch:

```
set(ah1,'XTickLabel','')
pos2(2) = pos1(2) - pos2(4);
set(ah2,'Position',pos2)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks. Too bad the width is stored in the position array so one can't use `linkprop` to make sure the plot doesn't become weird when hiding the colorbar again...

Comment: if you want to keep the aspect ratio of the image (e.g., using `imshow`) this solution will not work... You'll need to use `imagesc` instead.