# Automatically align image and graph with shared x-axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have an image that I want to plot under a graph showing the intensity of an arbitrary row of this image.

Apparently, there is no way I can "automatically" make the two graphs both **aligned** (they share the same x-axis) and **not distorted**.

Here is a MWE that uses the `kobi.png` image that should come with MATLAB. For this solution I used the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808143/how-can-i-align-plots-graphics-in-subplots-in-matlab), but it's not exactly what I am looking for. The reason will be clear after the code.

```
im = imread('kobi.png'); % read default image
img = rgb2gray(im); % convert to grayscale

y = 600; % select line to "scan"

% plot image with highlithed line
subplot(3,3,4:9);
imagesc(img);
colormap gray
hold on
line([0 size(img,2)], [y y], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 1.5);
hold off
axis image

photoAxs = gca;
photoAxsRatio = get(photoAxs,'PlotBoxAspectRatio');

% plot intensity of selected row
subplot(3,3,1:3);
r = img(y, :);
plot(r);
axis tight

topAxs = gca;

% adjust ratios
topAxsRatio = photoAxsRatio;
topAxsRatio(2) = photoAxsRatio(2)/2.4; % I want to get rid of this number!  
set(topAxs,'PlotBoxAspectRatio', topAxsRatio)
```

[image: Result]

As you can see, this produces (almost) the expected result, but there is an hardcoded number (that in the answer I linked was different, `3.8`, while here is `2.4`), that I would like to eliminate. Also, I think this number gives only an **apparently** aligned solution, but with my slight OCD this room for error gives me the creeps!

So the question is:

Is there any viable way to **automatically align a graph and an image** that have the same x-axis while **maintaining the image aspect ratio**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old code:

```
topAxsRatio = photoAxsRatio;
topAxsRatio(2) = photoAxsRatio(2)/2.4; % I want to get rid of this number!  
set(topAxs,'PlotBoxAspectRatio', topAxsRatio)
```

New code:

```
photoratio = photoAxs.PlotBoxAspectRatio(1)/photoAxs.PlotBoxAspectRatio(2);
ratio = photoratio * photoAxs.Position(4)/topAxs.Position(4);
topAxs.PlotBoxAspectRatio = [ratio, 1, 1];
```

Result:

[image]

---

**A bit of explanation:**

When figures are first plotted, you will notice only the heights are different, although you can clearly see the widths are also different.

I'm not 100% sure the reason Matlab does this, but this is my guess.

Usually, two properties, width and height, are sufficient to define the size of a 2D figure, but Matlab introduces an extra property, `PlotBoxAspectRatio`, to control the size. To avoid conflict, Matlab decides to give the width property a fixed number when a figure is first created. However, the actual width is calculated by `height*PlotBoxAspectRatio`.

Therefore, we have:

```
TopAxis.width = TopAxis.height * TopAxis.ratio 
Photo.width = Photo.height * Photo.ratio
```

In order to preserve the initial height of the TopAxis, we can only change the aspect ratio.

Let

```
TopAxis.width = Photo.width
```

We have

```
TopAxis.height * TopAxis.ratio = Photo.height * Photo.ratio
TopAixs.ratio = Photo.ratio * Photo.height / TopAxis.height
```

And the Matlab code equivalent is the new code proposed.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is excellent, and it explains that 2.4 (that was actually correct). It is the ratio between the heights of the two figures, isn't it? :)

Comment: @UJIN Indeed, I didn't realise that :D