# Convert B/W image to signal for Fourier Transform (DFT)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signals, fft

I am pretty new to signal and image processing.
I attached a picture of what I am supposed to do from a paper (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6501/ab7f79/meta).

[image]

Basically, an interferogram is recorded by a CMOS sensor in B/W, then each vertical and horizontal pixel line is taken singularly and "associated" with a signal representing the intensity of light reaching the sensor. Then, the signals are Fourier-transformed to extract information about frequency and phase (to unwrap using).
I have understood the final passage for the DFT of the signal, but I am stuck when I have to take the pixel line and the signal associated with it.
Ideally, in Matlab the workflow would be:

- extract each pixel line
- assign a "colormap" to the line (white = 1, black = 0, all the other shades in between?)
- build my signal interpolating the values of the pixels
- DFT the signal to extract frequency and phase

Is there a compact way to do so?

So far I managed to do this:
[image]
I imported the image of the interferogram (248x320 pixels, just a snapshot from the paper) and for the 124th horizontal line I obtained the signal, frequency and phase.

Comment: Try looking at [imread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html), it returns (for an input B/W image) a matrix with the grayscale level of each pixel.

Comment: [Does that help ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65902499/4363864)

Comment: Ok, I tried to use imread on the interferogram in the picture. I followed this (https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/261707-how-to-convert-an-image-to-frequency-domain-in-matlab) considering the green channel in this case. What I got it's a matrix whose rows and columns are the horizontal and vertical lines I would need, is that correct? Because I have just plotted a row and I got a signal that is quite similar to the one in the picture, don't know if that's just luck though

Comment: To normalize the pixel intensities from **0 (black)** and **1 (white)** the `im2double()` function can be used on the image returned from `imread()`.